ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java:230: error: cannot find symbol import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar
i am building a video conference app and using ZegoCloud SDK and UI Kit,
i get the following error when running the app on the android:
Launching lib/main.dart on SM M127F in debug mode...
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] Download native dependency
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] Native version: 3.16.0.39779
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] The specified version SDK already exists!
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/internal/ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java:230: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: interface PluginRegistry
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/internal/ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java:236: error: cannot find symbol
    private static Registrar registrar = null;
                   ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/internal/ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java:269: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void createEngineWithProfile(MethodCall call, Result result, Registrar reg, FlutterPluginBinding binding, EventChannel.EventSink sink) {
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/internal/ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java:319: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void createEngine(MethodCall call, Result result, Registrar reg, FlutterPluginBinding binding, EventChannel.EventSink sink) {
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/ZegoExpressEnginePlugin.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: interface PluginRegistry
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/ZegoExpressEnginePlugin.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    private Registrar registrar;
            ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEnginePlugin
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/ZegoExpressEnginePlugin.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEnginePlugin
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/ZegoExpressEnginePlugin.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
    private void setupPlugin(Registrar registrar, FlutterPluginBinding pluginBinding, MethodChannel methodChannel, EventChannel eventChannel) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEnginePlugin
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/ZegoExpressEnginePlugin.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
                    method = this.manager.getMethod(call.method, MethodCall.class, Result.class, Registrar.class, FlutterPluginBinding.class, EventChannel.EventSink.class);
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEnginePlugin
/Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/ZegoExpressEnginePlugin.java:158: error: cannot find symbol
                    method = this.manager.getMethod(call.method, MethodCall.class, Result.class, Registrar.class, FlutterPluginBinding.class, EventChannel.EventSink.class);
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class ZegoExpressEnginePlugin
Note: /Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/internal/ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/ahmedelsayed/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_express_engine-3.16.0/android/src/main/java/im/zego/zego_express_engine/internal/ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
10 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':zego_express_engine:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --info option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

my app build gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.lawh"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.lawh"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = '2.2'
        // manifestPlaceholders = [appAuthRedirectScheme: "com.example.lawh", 
        //                     applicationName: "lawh"]

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}






dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
  implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0'  
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
  implementation files('/Users/ahmedelsayed/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/flutter.jar')
}

my project level build gradle:
    allprojects{
        repositories {  
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion   = 34                // or higher / as desired
        targetSdkVersion    = 34                // or higher / as desired
        minSdkVersion       = 21                // Required minimum
        appCompatVersion    = "1.4.2"           // or higher / as desired
        playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"  // or higher / as desired
    }
    buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    }


my settings.gradle :


pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}



plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.3.1' apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.21" apply false
}
// dependencyResolutionManagement {
//     repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
//     repositories {
//         google()
//         mavenCentral()
//         maven { url 'https://storage.zego.im/maven' }  // <- Add this line.
//         maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' } 
//     }
// }

include ":app"

my pubspec.yaml:
name: lawh
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.4 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^2.31.0
  flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  animations: ^2.0.11

  intl: any
  country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  bloc: ^8.1.4
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.6
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.5
  toastification: ^2.3.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  image_picker: ^1.1.1
  image_cropper: ^8.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.6 
  url_launcher: ^6.3.1
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  user_repository:
    path: packages/user_repository
  update_repository:
    path: packages/update_repository
  payment_repository:
    path: packages/payment_repository
  
  http: any
  zego_express_engine: 3.16.0
  zego_uikit_prebuilt_video_conference: 2.9.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/social_media/
    - assets/images/
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true

i also tried the last version of zego_express_engine and
zego_uikit_prebuilt_video_conference and get the same result
i tried to open the plugin project level build.gradle file but it did not work
i appreciate your help :D
